# self.tableview reload not working after app connects to the internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know that it has been many times stated this question but it seems i can't find a solution with my case. I have an application which has inside a view controller a container view controller which is a table view controller. In this table view are loaded some rss feeds. When i open my app with no internet connection my data are not appearing, but after i connect my app to the internet my table should be reloaded after i pull down the table, but it doesn't. I tried many things but i can't find a solution. I am posting my code so if anyone could help i would appreciate it. Thank you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url"];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];

Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;

if (networkStatus == NotReachable)
{

    number = 0;

}
else{

    number = 1;
}



if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    num = 5;

}
else{
    num = feeds.count;
}}
```

These are my main methods for calling the table

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return number;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if(feeds.count > num){

    return num + 1;

}

return num;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];



    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    // Set up the cell
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:15]];
    [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];

}

return cell;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

element = elementName;

if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

}

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

    [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

}

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [title appendString:string];
} else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
    [link appendString:string];
}

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

This is where i reload my data after pulling down

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

CGPoint targetPoint = *targetContentOffset;
CGPoint currentPoint = scrollView.contentOffset;

if (targetPoint.y > currentPoint.y) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}}
```

Comment: What triggers the actual loading of data from the network into the feeds array?

Comment: It is an RSS feed. But i solved it with the help of Edward L. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare the class that implements `scrollViewWillEndDragging` as implementing `UIScrollViewDelegate`? Try putting a break point inside that event handler and see if your code is getting executed when you pull down the list.

**EDIT**: You are only updating the `number` variable when the view loads for the first time and you are initializing it to 0 whenever there is no internet present. Hence, you are never going to get any rows because there are no sections to display it from.

Comment: My code inside scrollViewWIllEndDraggin is executed normally. I have putted a NSLog in there and also a break point to see what happens and it runs perfectly.

Comment: Have you checked `feeds` object when the table is reloaded to see if it contains valid data? I also noticed that there are no declarations of item anywhere, is that an instance variable?

Comment: Is it possible the data to be invalid if with internet connection i can load them and display them from the start. But when i open the app with no internet connection in the beginning and then i connect it to be invalid??

Comment: Oh I see what you are doing wrong. You're only checking for internet reachability when the view is loaded the first time. Hence, whenever you call reloadData, you're going to keep getting number = 0. In other words, you're not going to get any rows regardless of how many times you reload the data because your `number` of sections is always going to return 0.

Comment: YES!! You were right. I had to check it again and change the variable "number" into "1". I had already done that before but i was getting an error that i didn't pay much attention, because i thought that it was the same thing but it didn't. So i have put the reachability check now again there and i saw that the error was for this : - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath . And i had to add the declaration of parser again which i have in the viedidload. Is it correct?

Comment: Please mark the answer if that solved your problem =)